# GPG No Public Key

Tags: microsoft-windows, gpg

Emacs gives a error about not finding a GPG key.

## The Error

```
Failed to verify signature archive-contents.sig:
No public key for 066DAFCB81E42C40 created at 2020-08-22T21:05:02+0000 using RSA
Command output:
gpg: keyblock resource '/e/z_gis/gulfmx/c:/Users/jake9/msys64/home/jake9/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/pubring.kbx': No such file or directory
gpg: Signature made Sat, 22 Aug, 2020 21:05:02 CUT
gpg:                using RSA key C433554766D3DDC64221BFAA066DAFCB81E42C40
gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
```

## Weird Path

What is really weird is the *keybox* path given:

- `/e/z_gis/gulfmx/c:/Users/jake9/msys64/home/jake9/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/pubring.kbx`

The first part is what ever working directory I was in when Emacs launched:

- `/e/z_gis/gulfmx/`

## My Setup

- OS: Win10
- msys2 / mingw64
- Emacs 27.1

`gnu-elpa-keyring-update` version 2019.3 is installed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, on msys2, with the mingw64 version of emacs, which is 27.1, incidentally.

The problem I've found comes from emacs's package.el not agreeing (in msys2's context) with `gpg` on what to do with the `--homedir` argument.

As it is suggested [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-04/msg00230.html), package.el sets this argument to be `(expand-file-name "gnupg" package-user-dir)`, but, unfortunately, `expand-file-name` returns a path that starts with "`c:/etc...`" and `gpg` does not understand this syntax, and simply appends this string to the current working directory. This is then a meaningless path.

But on msys2 you can send "`/c/etc...`", instead, which `gpg` understands and uses as it is.

So, my solution is to set `package-gnupghome-dir` to your actual linux-style path "`/c/Users/jake9/msys64/home/jake9/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/`"

Now I realize you are using your msys2 home (and not your Windows home) so maybe you can get away with setting `package-gnupg-home` to just "`/home/jake9/.emacs.d/elpa/gnupg/`"

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing same issue with GNU's official Emacs install, since Emacs 27.1.

For now, the only way I found to fix it is to disable signature checking and verify all packages by hand.

In my `init.el` I have temporarily added:

```
;; disable because of elpa bug in emacs 27.1
(setq package-check-signature nil)
```

Hopefully the bug will be fixed in next release.